# How to create a authentication model to restful API using golang gin?

Tags: go, restful-authentication, go-gin

I hope to create a authentication model to my restful API. Hope to use API token and I'm using MVC in web service and I created a auth.go controller like this.

```
package controllers

import (

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "os"
    //"github.com/jinzhu/gorm"

)

type AdsControllerAuth struct {

}


func (ac *AdsControllerAuth)TokenAuthMiddleware gin.HandlerFunc {
  return func(c *gin.Context) {
    token := c.Request.FormValue("api_token")

    if token == "" {
      respondWithError(401, "API token required", c)
      return 
    }

    if token != os.Getenv("API_TOKEN") {
      respondWithError(401, "Invalid API token", c)
      return
    }

    c.Next()
  }
}

func respondWithError(code int,message string,c *gin.Context) {
  resp := map[string]string{"error": message}

  c.JSON(code, resp)
  //c.Abort(code)
}
```

It doesn't working for now can some one help do this or is there are any examples to refer?

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get a 401? Are you sure the tokens match exactly (including newlines)?

Comment: I able to make this run but can i know how to send toke to using curl I'm using `router.Use(TokenAuthMiddleware())`  and I'm getting `{"error":"API token required"}`

Answer (score 10):

I made my own middleware to check token like below:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

//JWTAuthMiddleware middleware
func JWTAuthMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        validateToken(c)
        c.Next()
    }
}

func validateToken(c *gin.Context) {
    token := c.Request.Header.Get("X-Auth-Token")

    if token == "" {
        c.AbortWithStatus(401)
    } else if checkToken(token) {
        c.Next()
    } else {
        c.AbortWithStatus(401)
    }
}
```

In the example, I'm using Header instead of FormValue.

Try out Chrome DHC extension to test: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-rest-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm